# Trouble sending multipart request

Tags: java, spring, web, multipart

I'm creating a new endpoint to upload and process excel and csv files.
I'm trying to create an endpoint using springs Multipart upload, but I cannot reach the endpoint from Postman or using curl in command line.

I have a RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/finance/ratecard")
public class RateCardController
```

and I am able to access other endpoints in this controller without a problem.
I added new endpoint to this controller.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void uploadExcelFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("meta-data") UploadRateCardRequest uploadRateCardRequest) { 
  //Unrelated logic here
}
```

And I'm trying to send POST request using postman, I haven't touched Content-Type header, it's generated by Postman, but I have had no success reaching it. I always get 404 error. [Postman Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W7yo.png)

I have tried adding consumes = "multipart/mixed" and "multipart/form-data" to @PostMapping annotation, but those changes had no effect.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some obvious request parameter in Postman, or is my controller set up wrong?

Comment: Please include the code in your question, don't link to snippets of code in images as that is totally unreadadble and needs the people who want to help click all the links. Include them in your question instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the post with code snippets, keeping postman as a picture, because it would further complicate things if I copied every part separately into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems in `uploadExcelFile` method, one of dependencies I was using could not detect valid beans for an autowired interface. That was causing this issue.
Nothing was wrong with Controller set up or postman config pictured in the post.